# What on earth does elasticsearch _all field contains?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been using elasticsearch in work but confused by `_all` field for quite e long time. The document says that

> The `_all` field is a special catch-all field which concatenates the
>   values of all of the other fields into one big string, using space as
>   a delimiter, which is then analyzed and indexed, but not stored

But do these "all fields" contains fields not analyzed, or not even indexed?

If anyone knows the answer, please kindly tell me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_all` field is a field which concatenates the values of all of the other fields into one big string, using space as a delimiter, which is then analyzed and indexed, but not stored. This means that it can be searched, but not retrieved.

The `_all` field allows you to search for values in documents without knowing which field contains the value.

**Example**
suppose you have indexed a document as below

```
{
  "first_name":    "sunder",
  "last_name":     "r",
  "date_of_birth": "1996-03-20"
}
```

ok then the all index field for this document will be generated which will be as follow

```
"sunder r 1996 03 20"
```

which is then analyzed and indexed(The _all field is just a text field, and accepts the same parameters that other string fields accept, including analyzer, term_vectors, index_options, and store.)
and the `_all` field is not present in the `_source` field and it is not stored or enabled by default

**Note**

> The `_all` field is Deprecated in ES 6.0.0.
>   `_all` may no longer be enabled for indices created in 6.0+, use a custom field and the mapping copy_to parameter

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer, but that doesn't answer the question `do these "all fields" contains fields not analyzed, or not even indexed?` Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: its written in answer right the _all fields are analyzed and indexed, but when you query the all_field index it won't show up in the search results.

Comment: Thanks so much! So the fields in your example document are all indexed fields. And if it has a field not indexed, _all will not contain the field, am I right?

Comment: yup, you got it, i think.